# Uneven vertical alignment with $\in$

Tags: math-mode, spacing, vertical-alignment

Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{commath}

\newcommand{\st}{\text{ s.t. }}

\begin{document}
\[
    (x_n) \text{ converges to } a
    \iff
    \forall \epsilon > 0 \;
    \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \;
    \st \forall n > N \;
    \abs{x_n - a} < \epsilon
\]
\end{document}
```

And the rendered output:

[image: output]

Why is `\in` being placed below everything else? Also, is there a way to "nicely" include `\forall` and `\exists` without manually spacing them with `\;` and `\,`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: That is its default glyph/position. Compare with for example `>` that has the same depth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is more of an extended follow-up comment to Przemysław Scherwentl's answer than a new answer. Too long to fit into a "comment" box...

Borrowing (stealing?!!) some code from @PaulGaborit's answer to the question [Why do all symbols in $x \in X$ have their own baseline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139929/5001), here's a visualization of the size and positioning of the symbols `\epsilon`, `\varepsilon`, `\in`, and `+`, using the default Computer Modern math font:

[image]

Note that `\in` is quite a bit larger than either `\epsilon` or `\varepsilon` and that the two math symbols are aligned on the math-axis line. Because the math-axis line is slightly *above* the half-way mark between the baseline and the x-height line, the upper edges of the `\in` and `+` symbols protrude further above the x-height line than their lower edges protrude below the baseline.

*Addendum*: Just for comparison, here's the output of the same code, but with the math font `newtxmath` (which is based on/derived from Times Roman) in use instead of Computer Modern:

[image]

Interestingly, the symbol `\in` is a bit smaller in the newxtxmath font than it is in Computer Modern; even so, the `\in` symbol is still clearly larger than the glyph for `\epsilon`. And, because `\in` is centered on the math-axis line and its lower edge touches the baseline, its upper edge clearly protrudes over the x-height line, whereas that of `\epsilon` does not (by design, of course). Another difference between `\epsilon` and `\in` is in the position of the middle bars: It's on the math-axis in the case of `\in`, but *well below* it in the case of `\epsilon`.

Either way, it's clear that the font designers were well aware of the need to keep `\epsilon` and `\in` easily distinguishable.

Comment: Where did you get that diagram? Seems interesting. First time am hearing about `math axis`.

Comment: @azetina - I got/borrowed/stole [!] the diagram and code from Paul Gaborit's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139989/5001...

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. It seems looks less out of place now.

Answer (score 2):

You are partially answering yourself. Because $\epsilon$ and $\in$ are rather similar, a typografic custom says that the latter should be big enough to see the difference. It is not under: it is centered, but big. Let us see:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\in<$ $\in\left<\rule{0pt}{3mm}\right.$

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first case `\in` is at the position od `<` (see the vertical alignment), in the second also, but the `<` sign is big. Do we say that it is placed below everything else?