# How to shift characters and numbers in math mode to make them vertically centered around the formula axis

Tags: math-mode, symbols, characters, baseline

In math mode, characters and numbers are placed on the baseline and develop upward and/or downward. How can they be centered vertically around the formula axis, as symbols such as `+` and `=` are?

For example in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$n=0\ d(C,P)$
\end{document}
```

The `n` should be shifted upward, the `0`, the `d`, the `C`, the comma and the `P` should instead be shifted downward. How can this be done automatically without having to manually set a raisebox value for each character and/or number?

Thank you for your help, it is very appreciated.

Edit:
I excuse for being unclear about what I want. To clarify, my goal is to achieve what's displayed in the image that egreg posted in his comment. I hope it is clearer now, thank you again.

Comment: Are you talking about superscript and subscript? Like `^n` or `_n`?

Comment: @Sigur But the slash after 0 has it a sense?

Comment: Do you want to have one of them right above the other?

Comment: @Sebastiano,  I have no idea. It is not clear what he wants. Maybe two separeted expressions: `$n=0$, $d(C,P)$` or `${}^n=_{d(C,P)}$.`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "how can [characters and numbers] be vertically centred around the formula axis like symbols are?"

Comment: In [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqH0B.png) top is the normal, bottom is with everything but the comma placed symmetrically with respect to the fomula axis. I hope you *don't* want that any longer.

Comment: @Sebastiano The slash is to separate the two expressions without creating two math environments

Comment: @Mico I've edited the question, hope it is clearer now

Comment: @Sigur No, I've edited the question for more clarity

Comment: @DũngVũ No, I want it to be like in the image that egreg linked in his comment, I've edited the question

Comment: @EdoardoSerra I won't tell, I don't want to be considered an accomplice in crimes against typography.

Comment: @egreg - Are you implying that the answer I posted makes me a type-criminal? :-)

Comment: @Mico The typography police might start chasing you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following screenshots show first what you *say* you want -- all letters, numerals, and commas centered vertically on the math axis -- and second what the normal typesetting approach produces, i.e., letters, numerals, and commas all placed on the baseline.

I very much hope that you will agree that the normal typesetting approach is to be preferred. Speaking for myself, centering commas vertically on the math axis borders on the preposterous...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0pt, paperwidth=3cm, paperheight=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Command to center argument on math axis:
\newcommand\vc[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{$#1$}}} 

%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414613/5001 for source of the following code
%% Draw a line per font metric (#1 color, #2 vertical position, #3 label)
\newcommand{\drawmetric}[3]{\rlap{%
    \color{#1}\rule[#2]{2.55cm}{0.05pt}%
    \raisebox{#2}{\scalebox{0.3}{%
       \tiny\selectfont\sffamily #3}}%
  }}
\newcommand\drawallmetrics{%
  \drawmetric{red}{0pt}{baseline}%
  \drawmetric{blue}{1ex}{x-height}%
  \drawmetric{red}{\fontcharht\font`X}{cap-height}%
  \drawmetric{cyan}{\the\fontdimen22\textfont2}{math axis}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rlap{ % 
  $\vc{n}=\vc{0}\ \vc{c}(\vc{C}\mathpunct{\vc{,}}\vc{u}\mathpunct{\vc{,}}\vc{P})$}
  \drawallmetrics{}

\noindent\rlap{ % 
  $n=0\ c(C,u,P)$}
  \drawallmetrics{}
\end{document}
```