# beamer how to control subscript vertical position

Tags: pdftex, texlive, subscripts, superscripts

subscript and superscript position depend in the presence of both.

[image]

How can I control only the position of subscript (or superscript) vertically without added both?

I'm using Beamer, although the same problem exists to latex.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558778/47927

Comment: Thanks. tensor package does the job, as when include both and use one empy. Is not there a global configuration?